# How do I 'merge' information on a user during different periods in a dataset?

Tags: pandas, dataset, data-science

So I'm working with a dataset as an assignment / personal project right now. Basically, I have about 15k entries on about 5k unique IDs and I need to make a simple YES/NO prediction on each ID. Each row is some info on an ID during a certain period(1,2 or 3) and has 43 attributes.

My question is, what's the best approach in this situation? Should I just merge the 3 periods for each ID into 1 and have 129 attributes in a row? Is there a better approach? Thanks in advance.

Here's an exmaple of my dataset

```
   PERIOD  ID   V_1  V_2  V_3  V_4  V_5  V_6  V_7  V_8  V_9  V_10  V_11   V_12    V_13    V_14   V_15  V_16  V_17  V_18  V_19  V_20  V_21  V_22    V_23    V_24   V_25  V_26  V_27   V_28   V_29  V_30  V_31   V_32   V_33  V_34  V_35  V_36    V_37    V_38  V_39  V_40    V_41  V_42  V_43
0       1   1  27.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  27.0   2.0  63.48  230.43  226.18   3.92   0.0   0.0  0.33   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   92.77   82.12  10.65   0.0   0.0  117.0  112.0   2.0   NaN   35.0   30.0   NaN   0.0   0.0   45.53  1.0550   0.0   0.0   45.53   0.0   0.0      
1       2   1  19.0  0.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  NaN  19.0   2.0    NaN  134.75  132.03   2.03   0.0   0.0  0.69   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  162.48  162.48   0.00   0.0   NaN   54.0   48.0   2.0   0.0   44.0   44.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   48.00     NaN   NaN   0.0   48.00   0.0   0.0      
2       3   1  22.0  0.0  0.0  NaN  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  22.0   1.0  21.98  159.08  158.08   1.00   0.0   0.0  0.00   0.0   NaN   0.0   0.0  180.90  180.90   0.00   0.0   0.0   39.0   38.0   1.0   0.0   33.0   33.0   0.0   0.0   NaN   46.59  0.0000   0.0   0.0   46.59   0.0   0.0      
3       1   2   NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  0.0  NaN  0.0   NaN   4.0   2.20  175.97  164.92  11.00   0.0   0.0  0.05   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0  281.68  259.63  22.05   NaN   0.0  109.0  103.0   4.0   0.0  152.0  143.0   9.0   0.0   0.0  157.50  3.3075   0.0   0.0  157.50   0.0   0.0      
4       2   2  28.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  28.0   8.0  73.93  367.20  339.73  27.47   0.0   0.0   NaN   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  504.13  479.53  24.60   0.0   0.0  233.0  222.0  11.0   0.0  288.0  279.0   NaN   0.0   0.0  157.50  3.6400   0.0   0.0  157.50   0.0   0.0
```

Here's an example of an output

```
    ID  OUTPUT
    1   1.0
    2   0.0
    3   0.0
    4   0.0
    5   1.0
    6   1.0
    ...
```

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) instead post them as text. Also Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @ansev updated the post with an example and an expected output

Comment: What is the logic to get 0 or 1?

Comment: @ansev I don't really know and that's the point. I have to find a general approach as I know very little about the data. The only thing I know is that the 0 or 1 determines if the user is a parent or not, based on the 43 attributes.

Comment: Use `df.groupby('ID').apply(yourfunc)` to group by ID and apply a func to decide 1 or 0 in output column